# I am trying to do chi2 test in r, but it's not showing me the observed values and I'm not sure why

Tags: r

```r
chitesting <- data.frame(TQ=c(22,5,9,10,24,11,4,6,9),
                        P=c(14,2,2,16,3,46,3,2,12))

chisq.test(chitesting)
chitesting$observed
chitesting$expected
```

have created this data frame but coming out as NULL when I try to look at the observed/expected scores! Very new to r so would appreciate any help!

Comment: `chisq.test(chitesting)` does the test, shows the results on the console, _and then discards it_. If you want to see `$observed`, then you need to store it, such as `quux <- chisq.test(chitesting); quux$observed`

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the result of your call to the `chisq.test()` function in a new variable because the `chisq.test()` function does not store these values in the passed in data frame:

```
chitesting <- data.frame(TQ=c(22,5,9,10,24,11,4,6,9), P=c(14,2,2,16,3,46,3,2,12))
chi_result <- chisq.test(chitesting)
print("chi_result:")
print(chi_result)
print("chi_result$observed:")
print(chi_result$observed)
print("chi_result$expected:")
print(chi_result$expected)
```

**Output:**

```
Warning message:
In chisq.test(chitesting) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
[1] "chi_result:"

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  chitesting
X-squared = 49.299, df = 8, p-value = 5.572e-08

[1] "chi_result$observed:"
      TQ  P
 [1,] 22 14
 [2,]  5  2
 [3,]  9  2
 [4,] 10 16
 [5,] 24  3
 [6,] 11 46
 [7,]  4  3
 [8,]  6  2
 [9,]  9 12
[1] "chi_result$expected:"
        TQ    P
 [1,] 18.0 18.0
 [2,]  3.5  3.5
 [3,]  5.5  5.5
 [4,] 13.0 13.0
 [5,] 13.5 13.5
 [6,] 28.5 28.5
 [7,]  3.5  3.5
 [8,]  4.0  4.0
 [9,] 10.5 10.5
```